# Safari 8 / iOS8 not saving to Database

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, pouchdb

I have a simple html Form, that should send the input with a put command to my PouchDB Database via the http adapter. 
This works as it should in every browser I tried (Firefox/Chrome/Android) but not in Safari 8 or iOS8 Mobile Safari.
Even more strange, Safari doesn't give me any error.
Anyone has a suggestion?

The Code is more or less like this:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://my.website.com:5984/test');
var addToDB = function(){

    var fragDB = {
        _id: "tags_" + tagarr + "_" + new Date().toISOString(),
        question: quest,
        right: right,
        wrong1: wrong1,
        wrong2: wrong2,
        wrong3: wrong3,
        source1: source1,
        source2: source2,
        tags: tagarr,
        tagsall: alltags
    }

    db.put(fragDB);

};

if(send){
    send.onclick = function() {
       addToDB();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1" charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery-tag-this.css?v=5">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class=l eft>
    <title>
      title
    </title>
    <h1>
   header
 </h1>
    <form class="form" name="theForm" id="theForm" action="#" method="put">
      <fieldset>
        <textarea type="text" name="frage" id="frage" placeholder="Hier die Frage eingeben"></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <p class="right">
            <input type="text" name="right" id="right" placeholder="Richtige Antwort" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="wrong">
            <input type="text" name="wrong1" id="wrong1" placeholder="Erste Falsche Antwort" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div>
          <p class="wrong">
            <input type="text" name="wrong2" id="wrong2" placeholder="Zweite Falsche Antwort" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="wrong">
            <input type="text" name="wrong3" id="wrong3" placeholder="Dritte Falsche Antwort" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <p class="source">
            <input type="url" name="source1" id="source1" placeholder="Erste Quelle" title="Der Link muss mit 'http' beginnen ..." />
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="source">
            <input type="url" name="source2" id="source2" placeholder="Zweite Quelle" title="Der Link muss mit 'http' beginnen ..." />
          </p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="simple-tags" name="simple-tags">
      </fieldset>
      <p class="button">
        <btn type="button" id="submit">Senden</btn>
      </p>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class=r ight>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tagthis.js?v=5"></script>
<script src="js/pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you using PouchDB 3.3.1? Can you post a live example to reproduce?

Comment: Yes I already updated to the newest version. Didn't make any difference. I've updated my question with an example

Comment: What's the error you see? Is it one of the errors listed here? http://pouchdb.com/errors.html

Comment: There is no error as far as I can see in the dev tools in safari. It just doesn't create a new document in the db. But if you have access to a Safari 8 Browser I could send you a link to test yourself

Comment: Maybe this one from your list: "... PouchDB object fails silently (Safari)? ..."  I didn't thought there is something special about the html, but I edited the question with the it, for safety.

Comment: Without a live example; it's really hard to debug your code. :(

Comment: Put a test site online here [link](http://testthis.my-router.de/). Does this help?

Comment: I don't speak German. What am I supposed to do to reproduce the error?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Just put some random data in the form. Only thing to mention,two fields need to have a link starting with http, but it doesn't need to be an excisting one. When you then click on the "Senden" Button, it normally should send the input to the database, which is not working on Safari

Comment: I don't see any error in the debugger, I don't really understand what's going on here, and I don't know what you mean by "not saving to Database." Sorry I can't really help you.

Comment: exactly that's the problem. Everything seems to work fine, but when I go to look up the created document in fauxton, it's not there. I don't know how to describe it better. Could it be, that it's a problem with the permissions?

Comment: I've heard that Safari doesn't accept cross-domain cookies, so yeah, it might be that. But without analyzing the network tab (or the CouchDB log), it's very difficult to tell. Try comparing the CouchDB log of Chrome vs Safari and see what the difference is.

Comment: Looking in the CouchDB log, there is no error at all. Only thing that is different in the log are these two lines:  `OPTIONS /test/_id` and `PUT /test/_id` Both are missing for Safari.

Comment: Maybe I have a clue. Found this here [link](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Working_with_Forms). But what should I put as form action?